# Renaming a UIDocument in iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, ios11, uidocument

I'm struggling to figure out how to rename an instance of a `UIDocument` subclass in an iCloud folder. I've tried saving the document with the new URL…

```
func renameDocument(to name: String) {

    let targetURL = document.fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent(name)
        .appendingPathExtension("<extension>")

    document.save(to: targetURL, for: .forCreating) { success in
        guard success else {
            // This always fails
            return
        }
        // Success
    }
}
```

…but this fails with…

> `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“<new-file-name>” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “<folder>”."`
>   `UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1A9ACC2B-81EF-4EC9-940E-1C129BDB1914/tmp/(A Document Being Saved By My App)/<new-file-name>, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Move
>   ), NSDestinationFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/<folder>/<new-file-name>, NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1A9ACC2B-81EF-4EC9-940E-1C129BDB1914/tmp/(A Document Being Saved By My App)/<new-file-name>, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c4e54280 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}`

…and just a simple move…

```
func renameDocument(to name: String) {
    let targetURL = document.fileURL.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent(name)
        .appendingPathExtension("<extension>")

    do {
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: document.fileURL, to: targetURL)
    } catch {
        // This always fails
    }        
    // Success
}
```

…which fails with…

> `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“<old-file-name>” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “<folder>”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/<folder>/<old-file-name>, NSUserStringVariant=(
>       Move
>   ), NSDestinationFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/<folder>/<new-file-name>, NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/<folder>/<old-file-name>, NSUnderlyingError=0x1c4c4d8c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}`

Both of these work fine for local files, and renaming iCloud files works OK in the `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` root view controller.

My guess is that there's some permission missing somewhere that allows the app to write to iCloud folders.

For info, the **info.plist** contains all the following keys…

- `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`
- `NSExtensionFileProviderSupportsEnumeration`
- `UISupportsDocumentBrowser`

Comment: Is the document open when you are trying to rename it?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference whether it's open or closed.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1413989-setubiquitous see if that helps. I'm pretty sure some of the normal file manager methods don't work in the iCloud container (though iOS 11 may have changed things…)

Comment: I'll take another look at that. I had a previous iOS 10 version that worked using that method, but I was under the impression that things had changed in iOS 11, since you can save a file to any location, in which case how do you know whether it's an iCloud or local folder… or some other location?

Comment: This may be one of those spots Apple missed assuming that any renaming would happen in their shiny new document browser. I've experimented with the browser a little but not enough to have found the rough edges yet (other than the need to get the info.plist stuff _exactly_ right for it to work).

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing this in the context of `NSFileCoordinator`? This is required. You shouldn't need any info.plist settings apart from `NSUbiquitousContainers`.

Here is my code for renaming iCloud documents:

```
///
/// move cloudFile within same store - show errors
///
- (void)moveCloudFile:(NSURL *)url toUrl:(NSURL *)newURL
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
    ^{
        NSError *coordinationError;
        NSFileCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];

        [coordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:url    options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForMoving
                               writingItemAtURL:newURL options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForReplacing
                                                       error:&coordinationError
                                     byAccessor:
        ^(NSURL *readingURL, NSURL  *writingURL){
            if ([self moveFile:readingURL toUrl:writingURL])
                 [coordinator itemAtURL:readingURL didMoveToURL:writingURL];
        }];
        if (coordinationError) {
            MRLOG(@"Coordination error: %@", coordinationError);
            [(SSApplication *)SSApplication.sharedApplication fileErrorAlert:coordinationError];
        }
    });
}

///
///
/// move file within same store - show errors
///
- (BOOL)moveFile:(NSURL *)url toUrl:(NSURL *)newURL
{
    NSFileManager *manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager;
    NSError *error;

    if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:newURL.path])
        [self removeFile:newURL];

    if ([manager moveItemAtURL:url toURL:newURL error:&error] == NO) {
        MRLOG(@"Move failed: %@", error);
        [(SSApplication *)SSApplication.sharedApplication fileErrorAlert:error];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Nice to see the which options someone else used to do this.  Much better than what I was using.  But I thought you were not to use the default FileManager in a Coordinator.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDestinationFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/<folder>/<new-file-name>`

You're trying to save the document outside of your sandbox. You can only write files inside your own container, so there's no way to do what you want. Please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com if you want an API to rename the current file.